# Initialize Button Different class in java

Tags: java, class, button, differentiation

I got a problem when I build a class to use its own module like VB.net, because I don't want to initialize the `Button`'s Label and TextField a lot of line in everyday, but I got an error when button didn't initialize it.

When I try to build the program below, I get the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Unknown Source) at java.awt.Container.add(Unknown Source) at EmployeeGUI.AddLayout(EmployeeGUI.java:57) at EmployeeGUI.(EmployeeGUI.java:28) at EmployeeGUI.main(EmployeeGUI.java:89)

Here is class code:

```
import java.awt.Button;
    public class Init{
        public static void initButton(String btntxt,Object...btn){
            String[] btnT = btntxt.split("\\\,");
            for (int i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
                btn[i] = new Button(btnT[i]);
            }
        }
   }
```

Comment: what is `EmployeeGUI`

Comment: Code in main class for call :<br/>Init.initButton("Add,Clear,Exit",btnAdd,btnClear,btnExit);

Comment: this error is not relevant for the code you posted. what is the 28th line of EmployeeGUI.java

Comment: sorry i cannot add this this page said it too long but the method for call is Init.initButton("Add,Clear,Exit",btnAdd,btnClear,btnExit);

Comment: post relavant codes. use pastebin for additional codes.

Comment: aw sorry i dont know how to do it

Comment: http://pastebin.com/ post additional codes and give us the link

Comment: http://pastebin.com/vujReQVU

Comment: in Init class  String[] btnT = btntxt.split("\\,"); this \\ have only 2

Comment: you never initialize `lblGender` so it's null you are adding null to a panel??

Comment: aw i just delete it when i cannot update to this page . i debug the button  already that parse to Init class is class cannot initialize . i want to parse button with pointers but java didn't allow us to use pointer =.=

Comment: you haven't initialize `lblGender,btnAdd....` .for example you have initialize pnlgender panel using         `pnlGender = new Panel(new FlowLayout());`you have initialize .but where have you intialize `lblGender` ?? .see my answer

Comment: =.=" aw i want to build module like Vb.net . u didnt get my point

Comment: that's because of java pass by value not reference

Comment: read http://www.javaranch.com/campfire/StoryPassBy.jsp

Comment: thank bro . now ,i solve it already.

Comment: excactly, java didn't allow us to use pointer so i need to make button to array class and pass that . finish

Comment: And  Null is Button that i want to initialize in other class  but cannot get Data back in Main Class